# Yii CActiveDataProvider data is not loading from joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cactivedataprovider

My code :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

//  $criteria->select = array("id");

$criteria->with = array('userProfiles'=>array(
    'select'=>'firstname'
));
$criteria->together = true;

$criteria->condition = "firstname like '%$q%' "
        . "and (user_id not in (select id2 from friends where id1=$user_id) "
        . "and user_id not in (select id1 from friends where id2=$user_id))";

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Users", array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
));

return $dataProvider;
```

Notes:

1- `userProfiles` relation is defined in User module

Issue:

It is loading data only from User table not also from the user_profiles table despite of providing select atribute `'select'=>'firstname'`

I want data from both `user` and `userProfile` table.

Comment: isn't it simply a misspelling of `Users` ? Isnn't it only `User` in you activedataprovider ?

Comment: Its working, not spelling issue?

Comment: show userProfiles relation

Comment: @Alex, 'userProfiles' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'UserProfile', 'user_id'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relation self::HAS_ONE can't be executed together with main query, try use join

$criteria->select = "*, user_profiles.firstname firstname";
$criteria->join = 'user_profiles ON user_profiles.user_id = users.id';

Something like this, but you should create firstname field in User AR to retrieve it.

Or change relation to HAS_MANY and check first entity of array.

[together](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr): whether the table associated with this relationship should be forced to join together with the primary table and other tables. This option is only meaningful for HAS_MANY and MANY_MANY relations.

Because you can't write query that will give you only one record for each joining record

```
SELECT * FROM main
INNER JOIN slave ON (slave.main_id = main.id limit 1) // will not work);
```